# Forecasting Question

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am looking through Rob J Hyndman's text of forecasting [here](https://github.com/robjhyndman/fpp2/blob/master/Ch10Data/tourism.R)
In line 258, I am getting this Error Message:
Error in forecast::autolayer(f.arima, PI = FALSE, series = "ets") : 
  object 'f.arima' not found
I get that the object is not found, is there something I am missing here?[image]

Comment: This question is off-topic for this board. Aside from that, clearly the object `f.arima` is not defined earlier in the code and so is not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there's an error in the script. Intention seems to be to compare hierarchical model fit (distributed using "bottom-up" method) to the fit of ETS model. You could do it in place:

```
autoplot(allts(fcsts.comb)[,1])+
  geom_point()+
  forecast::autolayer(allts(fcsts.bu)[,1], series="BU")+
  forecast::autolayer(forecast(ets(allts(tourism.hts)[,1])),PI=FALSE, series="ets")
```